# Suddenly can't connect to raspberry pi using ssh in xbmc

Tags: ssh, kodi

I have installed the xbmc image on my raspberry pi, which uses dropbear in order to provide ssh connectivity. The raspberry pi receives a local and fixed ip from my dhcp server (192.168.1.102).

After some time, I am no longer able to connect to my raspberry pi via ssh, albeit I am able to ping it. In addition, it has internet connectivity, since I am able to up and download files to it.

Anybody has faced the same behaviour? Is there any possibility to find something in the logs in order to identify the causing problem?

**Edit**
In the syslog file I found just the following line about ssh or dropbear:

Jul 12 14:31:05 raspbmc xinetd[1655]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/ssh [file=/etc/xinetd.d/ssh] [line=12]

cat /etc/xinetd.d/ssh gives the standard configuration:

service ssh
{
disable = no
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
protocol = tcp
server = /usr/sbin/dropbear
server_args = -i
flags = IPv6
}

Unfortunately, journalctl or systemctl status  are not installed.

Comment: And what does it tell you the SSH when you use `verbose` flag? E.g.: `ssh -v user@host`

Comment: At the moment, I am not able to reproduce the error. If I can encounter the problem again, I will post the output of the above command.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like that problem is only on SSH client - since it's the only service which is not responding.

So look for logs of [SSH](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH) and try to restart it. There is also `verbose` [flag](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/dropbear) when you are trying to connect using SSH - it should give you information in which part SSH login failed (you haven't supply a lot of information like error messages etc...).

If you are using `systemd` as a daemon manager it's really easy to track log files with `journalctl` or `systemctl status <unit>`.